# How To change Command Text and ImageButton of ItemTemplate in TemplateField

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

I have a column that has an ImageButton. my database field has `bit` data type. I want when my record has true  value in that column show `True.jpg` and my command become `MakeFalse` and when it has false value show `False.jpg` and my command become `MakeTrue`. How I can do this?Is it possible to do it with one `TemplateField`?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could include two ImageButtons in a `TemplateField` and evaluate Visible from your `bit_field`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="YourField">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="True.jpg" Visible='<%# (bool)Eval("bit_field") %>' />
        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="False.jpg" Visible='<%# !(bool)Eval("bit_field") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>     
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I'm not sure how you'd want your Command to tie in.

Answer (score 3):

This is the remaining part of the above Brissles code

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
    CommandName="Select" Text='<%#(bool)Eval("bit_field")? "Make False":"Make True" %>'>  
    </asp:LinkButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```