# How to set ImageUrl based on the value of a field in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following line of code which evaluates whether the value is true or false, if its true it will show an image if its false it shows a different one.

```
<itemTemplate>
<img alt="" id="Img1" 
 src='<%# MyAdmin.GetCheckMark((bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ShowImg"))%>' 
 runat="server" /></ItemTemplate>
```

Can I customize the Eval part in the back end code in c# and then pass a different variable to it for example in C# I want to do

```
  bool ImgFlag = false;
  if(Entity.ShowImg == false && Entity.SomethingElse == true)
   {
      ImgFlag = true;
   }
  else if(Entity.ShowImg == false && Entity.SomethingElse == false)
  {  
      ImaFlag = false;
  }
  else
  {
      ImgFlag = true;
  }
```

And then I want to use ImgFlag instead of ShowImg in my GridView on each row, so ImgFlag will determine which flag to show..

Or is there a better way?

The issue is that that eval depends now on two things.. not one as before.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does the trick

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Image runat="server" ImageUrlt='<%#(bool)Eval("bit_field")? "first.jpg":"second.jpg" %>'>  
  </asp:Image>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Or this

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="YourField">
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="True.jpg" Visible='<%# (bool)Eval("bit_field") %>' />
    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="False.jpg" Visible='<%# !(bool)Eval("bit_field") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819879/how-to-change-command-text-and-imagebutton-of-itemtemplate-in-templatefield/8820896#8820896)

Answer (score 1):

Eval actually returns a property, so you can just call it twice for different properties.

Kind of

```
MyAdmin.GetCheckMark2((bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ShowImg"),
         (bool)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SomethingElse"));
```

may help

Comment: But how would i be able to condition it.. like i need ShowImg to check if its false and if SomethingElse is True and viceversa